# Running Scrapy multiple times in the same process

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I have a list of URLs. I want to crawl each of these. Please note

- adding this array as `start_urls` is not the behavior I'm looking for. I would like this to run one by one in separate crawl sessions.
- I want to run Scrapy multiple times in the same process
- I want to run Scrapy as a script, as covered in [Common Practices](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script), and not from the CLI.

The following code is a full, broken, copy-pastable example. It basically tries to loop through a list of URLs and start the crawler on each of them. This is based on the [Common Practices](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script) documentation.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'my-spider'

    def __init__(self, start_url,  *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = [start_url]
        self.allowed_domains = [urlparse(start_url).netloc]


urls = [
    'http://testphp.vulnweb.com/',
    'http://testasp.vulnweb.com/'
]

configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
runner = CrawlerRunner()

for url in urls:
    runner.crawl(MySpider, url)
    reactor.run()
```

The problem with the above is that it hangs after the first URL; the second URL is never crawled and nothing happens after this:

```
2018-08-13 20:28:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://testphp.vulnweb.com/> (referer: None)
[...]
2018-08-13 20:28:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: put reactor.run() outside of for loop and try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `reactor.run()` will block your loop forever from the start. The only way around this is to play by the `twisted` rules. One way to do so is by replacing your loop with a twisted specific asynchronous loop like so:

```
# from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
...

@inlineCallbacks
def loop_urls(urls):
    for url in urls:
        yield runner.crawl(MySpider, url)
    reactor.stop()

loop_urls(urls)
reactor.run()
```

and this magic roughly translates to:

```
def loop_urls(urls):
    url, *rest = urls
    dfd = runner.crawl(MySpider, url)
    # crawl() returns a deferred to which a callback (or errback) can be attached
    dfd.addCallback(lambda _: loop_urls(rest) if rest else reactor.stop())

loop_urls(urls)
reactor.run()
```

which you could use also but it's far from pretty.